# Add Operating System/Language development Community

Tags: feature-request

I believe that it would be beneficial to have a community dedicated to Programming Language development or Operating Systems development added to the site.

Comment: Feel free to propose it on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) if it hasn’t already been proposed. (And if it has, support the existing proposal!)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be a proposal on Area 51.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like [there already was an Operating Systems site proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/55360/operating-systems). It got through the definition and committal stages, but never got past the private beta as there was not enough activity. Unless you know a way to greatly increase activity on such a site, it probably just doesn’t have a large enough audience to deserve a Stack Exchange site of its own.

Comment: There's gotta be a way to automate this answer! :)